# Cannot determine if service: vora-catalog is running

Tags: vora

After installation of SAP HANA Vora 1.2 on MapR 5.1, got below error messages and vora-catalog seems down.

Can anybody solve this problem?

> 2016-10-19 21:29:48,341 ERROR com.mapr.warden.service.baseservice.Service$ServiceMonitorRun run [vora-catalog_monitor]: Monitor command: [/opt/mapr/vora/warden-control.sh, catalog, check]can not determine if service: vora-catalog is running. Retrying. Retrial #1. Total retries count is: 3

Comment: 1)      Shut down all vora services on all nodes. 
Ensure, that also on OS level, no vora processes are still running.
2)      Start the vora discovery service first on all nodes. 
Please check, that the discovery service is up and running. 
The discovery service UI is available on port 8500.
3)      Start the vora-dlog service on all nodes where it is installed.
check via discovery service UI that the service is available.
4)      Start the vora-catalog service. 
check via discovery service UI that the service is available.
5)      Start other vora services.

Comment: The issue has been fixed the above steps and now work well.

Answer (score 1):

The follwoing step solve this issue:

1. Shut down all vora services on all nodes. 
   Ensure, that also on OS level, no vora processes are still running.
2. Start the vora discovery service first on all nodes. 
   Please check that the discovery service is up and running. 
   The discovery service UI is available on port 8500.
3. Start the vora-dlog service on all nodes where it is installed.
   check via discovery service UI that the service is available.
4. Start the vora-catalog service. 
   Check via discovery service UI that the service is available.
5. Start other vora services.

Comment: As for Step #1, you could use "ps -u vora" for checking vora processes are there or not. In hadoop cluster, you could use "clush -aB ps -u vora" to make sure that.

Comment: For clear MapR alarm, please delete /opt/cores/<core files>. "clush -aB rm /opt/cores/<core files>" is one of easy way to delete on all node.